# If I am cutting from one speaker to the next is there a more consise way to write than what I have?

Tags: screenwriting

Is there a simpler way to write the following scene where the camera cuts to the speaker every time the speaker is speaking?

Example:

```
INT. OFFICE - DAY

Velma is sitting at her desk. Mike walks in. 

CUT TO:
MIKE
Hi
CUT TO:
VELMA
Hi
CUT TO:
MIKE
What are you working on?
CUT TO:
VELMA
Homework. What about you? 
MIKE
Reading
```

Comment: I think this is perfectly on-topic. It's specifically asking about the directions in the screenplay, not the screenplay itself.

Comment: Screenplays do not tell the director/cameraman/editor what to do on a line-byline basis. Scriptwriters are waaaaaaay lower on the filmmaking totempole. The ONLY camera directions your screenplay should include are *narrative cues* where it is necessary to explain the story. CUT TO: is a narrative editing cue, not a camera cue, such instructions would be useless to a film production. You are just adding a lot of garbage noise to your screenplay which needs to be about DIALOG, ACTION, and SCENE DESCRIPTION, not trying to to do other professionals' jobs.

Comment: @wetcircuit when would i use a narrative editing cue? can you give an example? don’t you describe the scene sometimes in the screenplay?

Comment: You describe the 'scene'. You do not describe the 'film'.

Comment: @watcircuit in this scene i want to describe how it is shot. is there another place to describe how the scene should be shot? btw it's my project. so i'm also the director and if i wasn't the script writer i would still work with the script writer if he or she felt strongly about the way it is shot.

Answer (score 2):

Cutting back and forth between the speakers after every line of dialogue, especially when the lines are as short as what you have written, feels completely excessive and unnecessary. You'd be cutting back and forth every second or two, which would be disorienting. Furthermore, my understanding is that screenplays shouldn't contain such in-depth shooting instructions - that should be left to the discretion of whoever ends up directing your screenplay.

I'd recommend simply removing the instances of `CUT TO:` entirely, and if the director decides that there's a need to cut from one character to another, they can do that without the script having to tell them.

Comment: Advice taken. I might have to do the cut back and forth because the actors are in different locations. I know that's not normal but it's a low budget project. If I had to do it like that then the director already knows this? Should I put in a comment in the action sequence or will they figure it out on their own?